# Can post-modifiers be used like pre-determiners without using commas?

Tags: post-modifier, predeterminers

I have many friends.  One friend is named Mike.  Mike is good at math, but I'm not saying whether my other friends are good at math or not.  I believe I can convey this information in one sentence like this:

> One of my friends, good at math, is Mike.

Assuming this is correct, can I also get rid of the commas and still have a grammatical sentence that means the same thing?  Like this:

> One of my friends good at math is Mike.

In summary, can post-modifiers be used as if they were pre-determiners without commas?

Comment: It’s my last question about pre-determiners, thank you.

Comment: I asked for the exam. Please don’t comment why I don’t use commas.

Comment: Without commas, the adjective phrase "good at math" is restrictive in the same way that a restrictive relative clause would be, cf. "one of my friends [who is good at math] is Mike". Inserting commas marks the AdjP as a supplement, i.e grammatically non-restrictive though, in this case, semantically similar. Incidentally, there's no pre-determiner in your example. It's a partitive fused-head construction with where the fused head "one" is followed by the partitive complement "of my friends". In simple terms it means "One friend from a set of my friends is good at math".

Comment: @BillJ I was taught ‘one of’ is a quantifier so a determiner. I think I’m wrong.

Comment: "One of my friends good at math" is a noun phrase in which "one" is the head word with the preposition phrase "of my friends good at math" functioining as its complement.

Comment: As someone who learned English at my mother's knee, and is not a trained linguistician, I am confused, first because your title question is ungrammatical. I think you mean *Can post-modifiers be prioritised, without commas, where pre-modifiers can't?* It would also help if you would give an equivalent pre-modifier example. I also agree withthe person who says it is an "unnatural sentence". Though idiomatic a more usual way of saying it would be "One of my friends who is good at maths is Mike".

Comment: @BillJ Though, I have a feeling that ‘he has twice my money burnt in the fire’ and ‘he has twice my burnt money’ are different. The former says, I think, he has no burnt money, but the latter says definitely he has burnt money.

Comment: @BillJ For example, he has twice my money hidden in my house, and he has twice my hidden money.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what's *actually* being asked here, but I do know that the initial premise (that *One of my friends good at math is Mike* means the same thing with or without commas) is incorrect. As @BillJ says, the commas / pauses are semantically significant (does the assertion unavoidably ***entail*** the fact that the speaker has more than one friend who's good at math?).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on a false premise (that the commas aren't significant in the text under consideration).

Comment: @FumbleFingers That’s okay. I will delete my post. It isn’t deleted!!!!

Comment: I always prefer trying to fix a question rather than deleting it or closing it.  I believe I have done so now.  user284747, could you review the edits I made to your question and make sure that it is still asking the question you wanted answered?  I believe the way I wrote it is clearer and avoids false assumptions... but it's possible that I misinterpreted your question because of the mistakes made, so I need you to check it.

Comment: @Richard Winters Thank you, I checked, and it’s finer.

Comment: As both your example sentences are unnatural, it's impossible to say whether removing the commas is allowable in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  This doesn't work as you intend.

It is just not clear how that post modifier is supposed to work. This is combined with an overly long subject and very short predicate to produce an unnatural sentence.

It would be hard to understand.  If someone want to know what you were talking about and took the time to think about it they might guess you meant to use some kind of relative clause but just made a mistake.

> One of my friends who is good at maths is Mike.

That is you have several friends who are good at maths, and Mike is one of them.

If you actually mean that Mike is your only friend who is good at maths you can't get that meaning by using post modifiers.  You need to rephrase. The first thing to do is to make Mike the subject, and "only" is a useful word.

> Mike is my only friend who is good at maths.

Comment: Though, I have a feeling that  ‘he has twice my money burnt in the fire’ and ‘he has twice my burnt money’ are different. The former says, I think, he has no burnt money.

Comment: Neither sentence would naturally be uttered.